# In ListView not all groups can be collapsed

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm building grouped ListView. I need groups be expanded and collapsed. [This article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31276/Add-Group-Collapse-Behavior-on-a-Listview-Control) almost did the trick.

The problem is that only first 3 groups are expanding and collapsing as needed (just like in article). Other don't get this behavior. Please see screenshot

[image: First 3 groups can expand and collapse, other - not]

This is how I add groups from SQL database:

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in terminalsTable.Rows)
        {
            ListViewGroup group = new ListViewGroup();
            group.Name = dr["name"].ToString();
            lineUpView.Groups.Add(group.Name, group.Name);
        }
        SetGroupCollapse(GroupState.COLLAPSIBLE);
        foreach (DataRow vRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            item = new ListViewItem(vRow["terminal_name"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(vRow["status_name"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(vRow["vessel_name"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(vRow["loading_window"].ToString());
            groupItems(item);
            lineUpView.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

SetGroupCollapse not really differs from CodeProject example:

```
    public class ExtListView : ListView
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case 0x202: // WM_LBUTTONUP
                    base.DefWndProc(ref m);
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LVGROUP
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public int mask;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pszHeader;
        public int cchHeader;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pszFooter;
        public int cchFooter;
        public int iGroupId;
        public int stateMask;
        public int state;
        public int uAlign;
    }

    public enum GroupState
    {
        COLLAPSIBLE = 8,
        COLLAPSED = 1,
        EXPANDED = 0
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr window, int message, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    void SetGroupCollapse(GroupState groupState)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= lineUpView.Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            LVGROUP group = new LVGROUP();
            group.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(group);
            group.state = (int)groupState;
            group.mask = 4;
            group.iGroupId = i;
            IntPtr ip = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                ip = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(group.cbSize);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(group, ip, false);
                SendMessage(lineUpView.Handle, 0x1000 + 147, i, ip); // #define LWM_SETGROUPINFO (LWM_FIRST + 147)
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (null != ip)
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ip);
            }
        }
    }
```

Could you please point me, why only first 3 groups can be extended and collapsed?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in SetGroupCollapse and check the Groups.Count value, if it is 3 then it means at the time of calling this function only 3 groups were created ...

Comment: I did it already, there are number of groups - 11. I don't know if I can attach screenshot to comment. But anyway, there are 11 and I can prove it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is one I have also experienced recently.  It is due to the fact that it is not guaranteed which `ID` each group will have.

In my scenario, I have 10 groups numbered from 0-10, with group `ID=1` missing completely.  I believe this is due to a previously reported bug with Microsoft ListViews that has not been resolved.

In order to work around it, it's possible to use Reflection to obtain the actual `ID` of each of the groups in the ListView (of course, replacing `MyListView` with the name of your own `ListView`):

```
int[] groupIDs;
FieldInfo listGroupIDMember;

listGroupIDMember = typeof(ListViewGroup).GetField("id", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
groupIDs = new int[MyListView.Groups.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < MyListView.Groups.Count; i++)
{
    object result = listGroupIDMember.GetValue(MyListView.Groups[i]);
    if (result != null && result is int)
        groupIDs[i] = (int)result;
}
```

This will produce an array with the *actual* `ID` of each group.

In my case, if I dump the `groupIDs` array, I can see that I have the following group IDs:

```
0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10
```

Instead of a counter from 1 to the number of groups, use the `groupIDs` array instead in your `SendMessage` function. In your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= groupIDs.Length; i++)
{
    int groupID = groupIDs[i];
    ...
    group.iGroupId = groupID;
    ...
        SendMessage(lineUpView.Handle, 0x1000 + 147, groupID, ip);
    ...
}
```

Note that I have replaced `i` in your code with `groupID` but you could obviously do this however you wanted.